# Automatically add parent category to model's ManyToManyField when assign it child category

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.7.9. I have Category class based on django-mptt and model with ManyToManyField:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How can I automatically add parent category to the Item's ManyToManyField when assign it child category? For example. I have a parent category called,'Music', which has sub-categories, 'Rock', 'Metal', 'Classic' etc.
When I assign 'Classic' to the Item, 'Music' must add automatically.
What is the right way to do it? I've tried to do it like this and it's wrong:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                
            if self.category.parent:
                for parent in self.category.get_ancestors:
                    self.category.add(parent)                
            super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: why it is wrong, what it gives you? and what is get_ancestors is?

Comment: Does the django-mptt docs help? http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html There is fairly similar example

Comment: get_ancestors() - gives all parent categories. ManyToManyField items can't be added to a model until after it's been saved. I know about this django-mptt example, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I've found the solution by myself.

```
from django.db.models.signals import  m2m_changed

def add_parent_categ(sender, instance,action,reverse,  *args, **kwargs):
if action == 'post_add' and not reverse:       
    for categ in instance.category.all():          
        for parent in categ.get_ancestors():
            if parent not in instance.category.all():                    
                instance.category.add(parent)
m2m_changed.connect(add_parent_categ, sender=Item.category.through)
```